# Legit way to handle hardcoded lists/options/dropdowns etc

Tags: ios, objective-c, enums

Multiple times during my work I am using different types of UI lists like menus or dropdowns.

Example from my recent: project I had 2 buttons, each was showing a popover with 3 hardcoded options let say A,B and C. Each option had it's own translations and effect on applications.

Many times I had a problem how to handle it cleverly. In Java we can enumarate through enums with string.

How to handle it in one place in objective-c? By handle I mean:

- store list of options
- present them all in Popover
- translate them
- recognize (switch) between options

There are many possibilities like:

- use only NSDictionary with keys - but then we have to write big
  if-else statements identifying options by key-values
- we can mix Enum and NSDictionaries/Array with keys and use switch statements BUT every change in list requires change on enum as well as array/dictionary. What's more the order of list and enum is essential.

On stack we can also find multiple ways to "translate"/"convert" enum to NSString but these solutions seems to be a bit redundant.

So my question is - what is the most legit way to handle option lists like these? Of course I'm not asking about full implementation of Popover ;) Just the data handle/store part.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would have the options in a plist.  Then load the plist contents into an NSDictionary.  Although you cant easily fix the issues you outline, you will save code time doing this approach - you can edit the plist much quicker and easier, you can get an array of 'allKeys' from the NSDictionary and loop through them, etc.